# using checkboxes to check data when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, math, checkbox

me again, iv tried following the android checkbox example, and whilst it has worked the most part, i need the code to only be initiated when a button is clicked, there is only one button in the program and this button is also used to do the maths calcs.
I think i would need a nested if statement, but im just wondering if any of you guys could help me with the construction of this, when the checkBox is checked, i would like it to check if there is data in the text field next to the checkbox, if there is data i would like the program to bring up an error statement, although this is only to be done once the calculation button has been called on.
can anyone give me any help on constructing this, i have tried adding listeners but i already have one on the calc button and if i add more into this method, i get error messages :/ 
There are three checkboxes, all used to check different field, however i also only want one checkbox to be checked at any one time and only if there is no data in the text field that applies to this.
cheers guys, sorry if im a bit vague but im starting to loose my rag with my lack of knowledge.
cheers

```
public class Current extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_current);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

      Button calc1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.current_calculate);

        calc1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              CheckBox checktime = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.custom1);
               CheckBox checkcurrent = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.custom2);
               CheckBox checkcharge = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.custom3);

               public void onClick(View v) {


                        //i would like this part to check that checktime is checked and that there is no data in editText Time1
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {



                    Toast.makeText(Current.this,
                       "Bro, try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }





                        //i would like this part to check that checkCurrent is checked and that there is no data in editText current1
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Current.this,
                       "Bro, i mean it ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



                        //i would like this part to check that checkCharge is checked and that there is no data in editText charge1
                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    Toast.makeText(Current.this,
                       "Bro, try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            // please note that i have not yet added the current.text field yet as i cannot be bothered with it throwing up errors just yet, please bear
           // in mind that i will be doing another two sums on this program, the next sum will be current1 / time1 and then the next will be charge1/current1
          // any help would be much appreciated, for now i only want the program to check that EditText current1 is empty and if so do the calculation bellow

                EditText Charge1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_2);    
                EditText Time1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_3);
                TextView Distances_answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distances_answer);
                double charge = Double.parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
                double time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());
    //Time is a class in Java
                Distances_answer.setText("" +charge*time);

        }
    });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(View v) {


                        //i would like this part to check that checktime is checked and that there is no data in editText Time1

if(Time1.length()==0){
               checktime.setChecked(true);


                    Toast.makeText(Current.this,
                       "Bro, try Android :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }





                        //i would like this part to check that checkCurrent is checked and that there is no data in editText current1
              if(current1.length()==0){
               checkCurrent.setChecked(true);



                    Toast.makeText(Current.this,
                       "Bro, i mean it ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }



                        //i would like this part to check that checkCharge is checked and that there is no data in editText charge1
               if(charge1.length()==0){
               checkCharge.setChecked(true);



                    Toast.makeText(Current.this,
                       "Bro, tryAndroid ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            // please note that i have not yet added the current.text field yet as i cannot be bothered with it throwing up errors just yet, please bear
           // in mind that i will be doing another two sums on this program, the next sum will be current1 / time1 and then the next will be charge1/current1
          // any help would be much appreciated, for now i only want the program to check that EditText current1 is empty and if so do the calculation bellow

               // EditText Charge1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_2);    
             //   EditText Time1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.number_input_3);
               // TextView Distances_answer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Distances_answer);
                double charge = Double.parseDouble(Charge1.getText().toString());
                double time = Double.parseDouble(Time1.getText().toString());
    //Time is a class in Java
                Distances_answer.setText("" +charge*time);

        }
    });
Just make sure that you findviewbyid all the edit texts before the button click.
```

Comment: Hi, cheers for you help, im getting an argument error for the True part on the .isChecked, any idea why this is ? thank you for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

First of all as it is onclicklistener for a button, v would always be button in your case. So `((CheckBox) v).isChecked()` would give runtime error. Change that to `checktime.isChecked()` or any other checkbox you would like to check its checked status. As for checking the emptyness of editext it can be done by `edittext.getText().toString().isEmpty()`